# How do I import immutable js into angular 2 (alpha)?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

I've tried:

```
import {Component, Template, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Immutable} from 'immutable/immutable';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@Template({
  inline: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>'
})

class MyAppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Alice';
    this.wishes = Immutable.List(['a dog', 'a balloon', 'and so much more']);
    console.log(this.wishes);
  }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

But then Immutable ends up being undefined.
Then I tried:

```
import {Component, Template, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Immutable} from 'immutable/immutable';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@Template({
  inline: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>'
})

class MyAppComponent {
  constructor(im: Immutable) {
    this.name = 'Alice';
    this.wishes = im.List(['a dog', 'a balloon', 'and so much more']);
    console.log(this.wishes);
  }
}
```

But then I get `Cannot resolve all parameters for MyAppComponent`. Can anybody help me with this?
And yes I've added the `immutable` folder to `System.paths`. Could it be that Immutable just can't be imported in an ES6 kind of way?

Comment: How do you tell Angular that your data is immutable?

Answer (score 5):

It was a small mistake. I had to change

```
import {Immutable} from 'immutable/immutable';
```

to

```
import Immutable from 'immutable/immutable';
```

Comment: If you use JSPM as package manager you need to `import * as Immutable from 'immutable'`